# How to change storage class of an S3 object with the Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

According to the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ChgStoClsOfObj.html), I'm supposed to set the source equal to the destination in the put request.
However, the [PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) offers no constructor to do this.

Is there any way to achieve this beside reuploading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is dedicated method for that in the SDK: [public void changeObjectStorageClass](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AbstractAmazonS3.html#changeObjectStorageClass-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.StorageClass-)

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss, i missed that.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution works, but the method [changeObjectStorageClass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#changeObjectStorageClass-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.StorageClass-) is actually deprecated.
The deprecation note suggests to use the method [copyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#copyObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest-), as in the following snippet:

```
    CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest= 
        new CopyObjectRequest(bucket, key, bucket, key)
        .withStorageClass(StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess);
    s3.copyObject(copyObjectRequest);
```

I could not notice any performance difference between the two approaches.

Comment: The API docs don't seem to indicate the changeObjectStorageClass method is deprecated. Do you have a link to where you found this information?

Comment: It's in the AmazonS3 interface, not the abstract class. The link is in my proposed solution.